# Usurance quoting system fails with error "No such file or directory: exec of /usr/lib/cgi-bin/cqsl.cgi"

Tags: apache, server, apache2, perl

I purchased a quoting engine but I am having a problem with the installation. I've followed instructions in the readme.html file (http://usurance.biz/readme.html), but I am getting an "Internal Error".

I reviewed the error.log, tried to make sense of the output and googled around but no answer.

Steps I took: (note: I verified CGI is enabled by running a test found here usurance.biz/cgi-bin/test.pl)

1. Placed the csql.cgi script in my /usr/lib/cgi-bin
2. Updated vhost to

   AllowOverride None
   Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
3. Updated user permissions on /var/www/usurance.biz with commands (googled):
   sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www/usurance.biz/html
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/usurance.biz/html
4. Placed TEMPLATE.HTM in /usr/lib/cgi-bin
5. Placed canmain.html and usmain.html inside public_html (as a test I changed the form action from action="/cgi-bin/csql.cgi" to action="http://www.usurance.biz/cgi-bin/csql.cgi". The latter gives a different error, a user permissions error.)
6. Created images and css directories
7. Accessed canmain.html and hit submit to find error.

My experience is limited (obviously), so as rudimentary the question I greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: 500 errors for CGI apps are a failure to execute. This is almost always an ownership and permissions problem. You have to use shell (SSH) or a file manager within your control panel to set the file permission of your .cgi file to execute. Set the execute permission for the user, group, and other. You will likely also have to set the file owner and group to match the username of the other files. If you are using a CGI wrapper, you may need to work with that too. How depends upon the wrapper. You may need to work with the company that supplied you with the script for more specific help.

Comment: Also, when I change the form action to the explicit url (usurance.com/cgi-bin/csql.cgi) the browser outputs a 'forbidden' error stating "you do not have permission to access /cgi-bin/csql.cgi on this server" which is different than the initial error page. I did create a cgi-bin inside the public_html directory for this domain, that was before I read an article stating all cgi scripts need to be placed in the /usr/lib/cgi-bin, so I am wondering if it's forwarding the request to that directory which is why we get a different error.

Comment: The directory/path depends upon what was already set within the web server or site. If there is no /cgi-bin/lib/ then do not worry about it. Articles or documentation on this matter have to be taken with salt. The error you are getting is a permission problem. You will have to set the file ownership and execute permission for your csgl.cgi file. Otherwise, it cannot work.